# Drawing with DirectX over a PowerPoint slideshow

Tags: wpf, directx, powerpoint

I need to be able to draw some DirectX content over a PowerPoint slideshow being played using PowerPoint Viewer in .NET application using Microsoft Interop API. So far I have come up with idea of displaying a WPF window with full transparency over Slideshow but to do this I will have to rewrite all my drawing logic in WPF(which is already written and working fine with DIrectX), so this is not really practical for me. Another way could be take snapshot of PowerPoint window and draw it in DirectX but it could cost pn performance as it needs to be done at least 30 times a second. I could not found any way to draw some texture keeping background transparent in DirectX. Can anyone suggest me what could be a better way to do so? Does PowerPoint API gave some way to do so? I can work with PowerPoint 2013 if there is some support. Any suggestion will be great.
Thanks in Advance.